# How to count the frequency of an element in an ndarray

Tags: python, numpy, count, element, multidimensional-array

I have a numpy ndarray of strings and want to find out how often a certain word appears in the array. I found out this solution:

```
letters = numpy.array([["a","b"],["c","a"]])
print (numpy.count_nonzero(letters=="a"))
```

> -->2

I'm just wondering if i solved this problem unnecessarily complicated or if this is the simplest solution, because for lists there is a simple .count().

Comment: If you want to check for a single letter, that's the basic way of going about it: build a boolean mask and count the `True`s. if you wanted to count the frequencies of all elements in the array, then a combination of `np.unique` and `np.bincount` would be much faster.

Answer (score 5):

You can also use [`sum`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html):

```
>>> letters = numpy.array([["a","b"],["c","a"]])
>>> (letters == 'a').sum()
2
>>> numpy.sum(letters == 'a')
2
```

Comment: @aldorado It may be useful to see what `(letters=='a')` looks like. In numpy this creates a mask, in this case it would be a 2x2 array of `True/False` values. Applying the sum over the mask counts the number of `True` values.

Comment: However, use [numpy.count_nonzero](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.count_nonzero.html) instead of sum(), since it's about 10x faster for those boolean values.